# area and perimeter calculation of various shapes

Tags: java, math

```
Area of a circle, rectangle, triangle, trapezoid, parallelogram, ellipse, sector.
Perimeter of a rectangle, square
```

Is there a java library which provides mathematical functions to calculate the above?

Comment: Mathematical functions?  Are you saying you need a library for these?

Comment: These should be trivial to implement and you don't need a special library for that

Comment: @dimitrisli - I just added more shapes to the question, I would love to use a library if one is available

Comment: @Jason, still ridiculous.   A library isn't necessary, and I doubt that it's the point.

Comment: @Jason Are you truly dealing with all these shapes, or are you more just curious?

Comment: Yes, I am dealing with all shapes

Comment: If you truly want "all shapes", you'd be better off with a general purpose contour integration routine that used polynomial or piecewise representations of 2D shapes.

Answer (score 4):

```
public double areaOfRectangle(double width, double length) {
  return width*height;
}
public double areaOfCircle(double radius) {
  return Math.PI * radius * radius;
}
public double areaOfTriangle(double a, double b, double c) {
  double s = (a+b+c)/2;
  return Math.sqrt(s * (s-a) * (s-b) * (s-c));
}
```

etc.

How hard can it be to code up yourself? Do you *really* need a library to do it for you?

You could also port [this C code](http://lernc.blogspot.com/2010/04/program-to-calculate.html) which implements area and perimeter calculations for *many* shapes.

Comment: I just added more shapes to the question, I would love to use a library if one is available.

Comment: marcog, your code needs some work.  your areaOfRectangle parameters don't match the values; there's no Math.pi, but there is Math.PI.  And you can't be serious about porting to C.  It's still not necessary.

Comment: @duffymo Agreed, it's totally unnecessary but I saw it in a quick google and thought it's worth a mention in passing.

Comment: Well apparently it's not *completely* non-trivial, as your `areaOfTriangle` method returns the wrong value :).  TBH, I too would like to see an answer which includes an actual library (and not just *"Do it yourself!"*), at the very least in the spirit of Don't Repeat Yourself.  Surely *some* graphics library out there has already done this?

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend that you use a library for such a thing.  Just look up the formulas for each one and write the single line of code that each requires.

Sounds like somebody's classic first object-oriented assignment:

```
package geometry;

public interface Shape
{
    double perimeter();
    double area();
}

class Rectangle implements Shape
{
    private double width;
    private double height;

    Rectangle(double w, double h)
    {
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
    }

    public double perimeter()
    { 
        return 2.0*(this.width + this.height);
    }

    public double area()
    { 
        return this.width*this.height;
    }
}

// You get the idea - same for Triangle, Circle, Square with formula changes.
```

Comment: Quite right! Looks like the goal is in understanding inheritance rather than geometry.

Comment: +1 for bringing the inheritance in the picture. classic example

Comment: Until one tries to make Square inherit Rectangle, and then, the world collapses...

Comment: Exactly right, Alexandre C.  The Liskov Substitution Principle goes right to hell: http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf

Comment: yeah, this is pretty much classical material, but it always rings a bell when I see `class Rectangle : public Shape`

Answer (score 1):

The only non trivial formula you asked for is the perimeter of an ellipse.

You'll need either *complete elliptical integrals* (google for that), or numerical integration, or [approximate formulas](http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/ellipse-perimeter.html) (basically, the "Infinite Series 2" is the one you should use)

Comment: It requires nothing of the sort. You generalize the equation for a circle pi*r*r into pi*a*b where a and b are the semiaxis lengths.

Comment: @Victor: I talk about the perimeter, not the area.

Answer (score -1):

For the general case you could get an close estimate with a Monte Carlo method. You need a good random number generator. Take a rectangle large enough to contain the Shape and get a large number of random points in the rectangle. For each, use contains(double x, double y) to see if the point is in the Shape or not. The ratio of points in the Shape to all points in the rectangle, times the area of the rectangle is an estimate of the Shape area.